# At what point can a micronation establish its own laws?

Tags: law, sovereignty, statehood

If I were to buy a plot of land here in Britain and managed to bring in enough citizens to start our micronation, and we then built enough buildings, and had a supply of food and water, would we able to establish our own laws seperate from those of British laws?

At what point is the theoretical micronation able to establish its own laws?

Comment: In theory: whenever you want. This seems to be a purely hypothetical quesiton.

Comment: Basic research would include a viewing of "Passport to Pimlico"

Comment: You don't need statehood to have your own laws.  Households, clubs, schools, workplaces, etc. all have their own rule systems.  Even SE has its own, relatively-vaguely-defined rules and justice system, though we're more focused on reform than punishment.

Comment: It's the other way around. If you can establish your own laws, you have a nation. Until then, you don't.

Comment: @immibis: I'd put it slightly stronger: if you can _enforce_ those laws, you're a nation.

Comment: No time to write an answer,  but you seem to be confusing (private) property and (public) sovereignty.

Comment: Imagine for a moment that you have established your own country within another.  Ignore how that came to be for a moment.  How would you handle your citizens establishing their own nano-countries within your micro-country?

Comment: @JimmyJames without wanting to get highly tangential in the comments, you could write into the constitution or even just prevent citizens from owning land. All citizens could just be on a land-rent agreement

Comment: Approximately the size of Monaco. And I think this question is not really useful in the current formulation, except maybe for worldbuilding.stackexchange.

Comment: @Charlie Is it possible someone else thought of that already?

Comment: You may want to compare [South Sudan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Sudan). It's certainly larger than a micronation, but many of the issues raised in answers would apply regardless.

Comment: @MSalters If you can't enforce them, have they really been established?

Comment: @immibis I think that's edging into philosophy

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The question is not "When can you enforce your laws on your land?", the question is "When can you prevent the United Kingdom from enforcing their laws on your land?". That's the case if any of these is true:

- You have an army strong enough to keep the UK government forces out of your country (being an armed insurgency would likely not yet give you international recognition but would make you capable of enforcing your laws nevertheless)
- You have an agreement with the UK which says that they grant you independence (like they offered to Scotland if they hadn't voted to remain)
- You have found international allies which formally recognize your nation and are able and willing to defend it against claims from the UK. Good luck convincing some notable international powers that siding with you is more beneficial to them than siding with the UK.
- If you would not be against the UK you could also try to get the majority of the UN member-states to recognize you and make a resolution defending your sovereignty, but the UK is a veto-power in the UN security council, so in this case it's the same as point 2.

Comment: I see. I like how you put it, great answer!

Comment: Just to clarify, the UK would have no legal obligation to give up rule of the land? It would essentially have to be bullied out of their hands?

Comment: @Charlie exactly. Private land ownership doesn't free you from the sovereignty of the state it belongs to.

Comment: @Philipp, that's particularly true in England, where you *don't* own the land, the Crown does.

Comment: @Mark it is not more or less true in England.  it is the same everywhere.  if you can prevent the UK from enforcing its laws on a parcel of land, then the UK does not own that land.

Comment: @Charlie The Crown owns everything some number of meters below the soil and a certain distance out to see. Even if you build something underground, the land the Crown owns is just moved to some number of meters below the lowest point.

Comment: @emory: I do own my own land. That ownership is a legal construct under Dutch law. The Dutch State doesn't own it. There are parts of the Netherlands which _are_ owned by the State, or cities, but this is the exception to the rule. ("Erfpacht"). In England, that's not exceptional. So it's _not_ the same everywhere, not even within a country.

Comment: @MSalters You own your own land *under Dutch law*. If you would *reject* Dutch laws by declaring yourself to be an independent micronation, you would also lose the protection of property rights the Dutch law provides and thus lose the legal claim to your land. But that's all just legal fiction anyway. In practice it doesn't matter how your state defines private land ownership. Fact is, no state in the world will recognize someone forming a micronation within it.

Comment: Related: [Republic of Minerva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minerva_Reefs) was created on international waters not controlled by any nation, but was soon after conquered by Tonga (over 400 km away), which did not want any new nations popping up near them.

Comment: @Philipp: It's actually not _that_ simple. On the border with Belgium or German, there have been border corrections, and those border corrections did not break ownership. Ownership, even of land itself, can transcend national law. And this is in fact entirely common. I'm the owner of my clothes of my car, and remain so when I travel across the border. It's just that moving land across borders is impossible, and you'd have to move the border itself to notice that quirk !

Comment: @MSalters The fact that land ownership remained after moving the border is only so because the country the land moved into allowed it to be that way.

Comment: @MSalters I suspect if North Korea and the Dutch state adjusted borders and your land became part of North Korea, then your clothes, car, land, and even person would no longer be yours.

Answer (score 26):

The misconception in your question is meaning of "buy a plot of land". In the strictest sense, you can't.

The Crown retains the ultimate ownership (Allodial Title) of all land in England and Wales. When we talk about buying land that's really a shorthand for buying a Freehold, which is a more abstract entity - it gives you a set of rights over a parcel of land, but not ownership of the land itself. The rights granted don't include the ability to abrogate any laws that apply to the land. In fact, the state remains the right to purchase the freehold back from you through Compulsory Purchase.

There is historical precedent for states buying and selling real land, and the right to make laws over that real land, such as the Louisiana Purchase. If you were able to negotiate the purchase of the real land from the United Kingdom them yes at that point you would be able to pass laws as you wanted. Even then however, if you passed laws that upset the UK enough it could attempt to bring diplomatic, economic or military pressure against you to make you desist - despite you being on a stronger legal footing.

Comment: Is there any historical precedent of a state selling land to an entity that was not previously already a state? In the case of the Louisiana purchase (and the Alaska purchase, etc.,) the purchaser was the United States, which was already a country. There is, however, precedent for part of a nation telling the government, "Hi. We have guns. We're not part of your country anymore. kthxbye." Sometimes that works out, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @reirab: [Nevada](https://law.justia.com/codes/nevada/2009/title-32/chapter-361/allodial-title/) ostensibly had a process for obtaining allodial title as recently as 2005, but it was arguably just a way of paying your property taxes in advance, rather than "true" allodial title.

Comment: @Kevin Interesting! But, yeah, that appears to be more a prepaid property tax program than anything else. Certainly, the United States government would not have taken the position that such titles entitled the bearer to create a sovereign nation outside of U.S. jurisdiction and it appears that all Nevada state and local laws aside from those related to property taxes still applied normally to the property.

Answer (score 8):

It does not work that way.

Basically, if you control the territory you can make the laws (the state is the monopoly of violence, by one definition).

If you are a few people but nobody challenges your claim, you are a nation. It being "micro" or not is not really an issue.

Of course, the question with your plan is the UK government is, to put it lightly, not likely to recognize your claim. So, the only way for your state to become a reality is to get enough power to wrestle control again from the UK. IOW, it is not going to happen.

Comment: How do you know who controls the territory? If I've bought the land doesn't that mean the territory within that land is my own?

Comment: And BTW, you are confusing the terms "nation" (which means a common, shared culture and is often rather vague) and "state/contry" (which is what you are asking about).

Comment: Easy to check. Break the UK law in an obvious way (I suggest growing marihuana, and writting a panel advertising it at the entrance of your "state") and see if the UK police enters to arrest you. If they do enter and arrest you, you are not in a different state.

Comment: @Charlie Simply owning land does not give you the authority to make laws on it.

Comment: @Charlie: The ultimate authority to make and enforce laws is generally known as _sovereignty_. It's quite independent from ownership.

Comment: @SJuan76 Well, whether that means you're a country or not kind of depends on how you react to said police. If you manage to successfully force them to leave without arresting you, you might have a better claim at being a country. Good luck with that, though.

Answer (score -1):

Your theoretical micronation can setup laws as soon as it is formed.  If you are in fact a sovereign state, then you get to make the rules.  That includes setting forth a constitution for guiding how rules will be created, updated, and enforced. 
 Once you have your constitution, get busy writing all the laws you need.

As you are likely aware, laws may be an important issue, but your country has a far more pressing matter at hand: Her Majesty's Army.

Comment: "As soon as it is formed" is quite vague, though. When is the micronation officially formed?

Comment: @Charlie, That's a very ambiguous.  There are no agreed upon methods for creating a country.  Most countries aren't very fond of upstarts taking away their territory, resources, and tax-base.  [Somalialand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somaliland) is a great example of a breakaway nation-state that you're suggesting.  Realistically speaking, you'll need the ability to operate autonomously within your territory (military, police, a constitution, taxation, etc).  SJaun76 points out "the state is the monopoly of violence, by one definition".  I find that rather accurate myself.

Comment: In actual fact, you would be treated like a cult and ought to worry about the police, not the army.

Comment: @Relaxed, "In actual fact", really?  Since it's an "actual fact" can you please give me a reference?  The level of response that you get from the government is going to be entirely dependent upon the size of your nation-state and the level to which it is already autonomous.

Comment: "When is the micronation officially formed?" – According to whom? To the citizens of you micronation, it is formed when they say so. To the government of the state your territory lies in? Probably never. A state (the same applies to a country) is a state (country) if other states (countries) recognize it as such. The question is difficult: the People's Republic considers Taiwan a rogue territory that is a part of their country. The Democratic Republic considers mainland China as a rogue territory that is a part of *their* country. Most countries do not officially recognize Taiwan as a country

Comment: but nevertheless treat it exactly like one. So, is Taiwan a country or not? Is Palestine? Basque? What do you think a Palestinian would answer? What would an Israeli answer?

Comment: I vaguely remember reading that HM Army (unlike the Navy and Air Force) is _not_ Royal for, um, historical reasons.

Comment: @ABailey Indeed, it will depend on the size. There are some notable examples of it indeed involving the armed forces, especially in the case of the U.K. And, in some of those examples, the armed forces lost and the new nation remained.

Comment: NB: There's no such thing as "Her Majesty's Royal Army": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Army

Comment: @AntonSherwood, Jcast, I've updated it to remove 'Royal'.  Thanks for the heads up.